# Problem in hosting a website on heroku in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, heroku

[image: heroku logs after visiting on hosted url]
The nodejs website is working fine while hosting locally on port 3000 but when I host it on heroku after pushing my code it gives this error while visiting this ([url](https://blogsbyaniket.herokuapp.com/)).

I was trying to host my nodejs build on heroku but it gave error which I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> code: 'MODULE NOT FOUND'

You also need to include and upload the `node_modules` folder to heroku. Please read the console errors more carefully next time around!

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replying. I have already pushed the node modules folder to heroku. Still this error is throwing